# Is there any public in-game data mining/knowledge discovery repository?

Tags: databases, data-mining

I'm taking an Introduction to Data Mining course at the university and we have to work on a final project.

As you may already know, it's difficult to collect this kind of data manually (specially when you're not working for a company of have the proper contacts).

Is there any public collection of in-game data in order to apply data mining algorithms? The kind of data I'm looking for is the sort of data they used in this paper "[Predicting Player Behavior in Tomb Raider Underworld](http://game.itu.dk/cig2010/proceedings/papers/cig10_023_085.pdf)".

Characteristics: playing time, number of deaths, causes of death, rewards, treasures. Other kind of in-game data (possible an MMORPG): race, level, equipment, guild, items usage, hp/mp rate, level-up mean time, hours played by day/week/month, log-in/log-off time, etc.

The kind of problems I'd like to tackle could be represented as questions like:

- What are the chances a player is likely to pass the game [in X seconds]?
- What are the best X guilds to be with in order to meet my expectations as a player and not end up being expelled?
- What is the best world area in order to level-up faster now while minimizing death possibilities?

Comment: "collection of game-related data" is rather vague. What kind of data are you looking for?

Comment: http://tf2stats.net?

Comment: @Byte56 Thanks for the review, I already improved the specificity as I was better-explained what to do as a final project.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou that site doesn't suit my needs because I need it in "raw" format, but thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure where you could find this, but I would suggest contacting someone at Blizzard about World of Warcraft. I feel like they would be the most likely to keep raw information of this type. Probably things like, how much money a player has, items owned/equipped, that kind of stuff. You seem to be looking into a rather under developed field, so I would suggest personally contacting companies about this information. You might also want to try the makers of 2nd life. I feel like they would track this stuff, and since you can make your own items, maybe you can make one to track data.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with developing a game?

Comment: @TrevorPowell: lots of companies these days are looking at metrics like this to decide how to design an improved player experience (or how to better monetize the user base...) so yeah, I'd say it's relevant.

Comment: @Kylotan I've worked at some of them.  But each of them has kept their metrics in-house and private.  And I'm not sure how (to use the question's examples) a player getting stuck on Level 3 of Angry Birds is useful at all to someone developing a different game, or how the knowledge that one levels up faster in Azeroth than in Kalimdor is useful to developing a different game.

Comment: @pctroll: RE: "that site doesn't suit my needs because I need it in 'raw' format"  Good to hear that you're getting your money's worth from that data mining course.  :)

Comment: Counter-Strike has some heatmaps (no raw data afaik though) http://blog.counter-strike.net/science/maps.html Also see someone working on a Unity system here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/49871/creating-a-heat-map-to-track-where-players-go.html

Comment: @TrevorPowell: I agree that game-specific data is not very generalisable. Data about install and play patterns might be useful however.

Answer (score 2):

It's not precisely deep data, but check out what Valve Software makes available at http://store.steampowered.com/stats/

The Day of Defeat stats at http://www.dayofdefeat.com/stats/ might be the closest for what you're looking for.  That said, none of the offerings have a lot of data.

You might also consider contacting Valve to see if they would share any additional data with you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a lot of the information that you're after companies would consider commercially sensitive. The reason they gather all that data is to help them make more money by improving their games. Giving away that information to their competitors is probably not something they'd want.

If you look at the acknowledgements on the last page of that pdf you mentioned it's clear that the authors work for the game developer.

Your best option is probably to write your own game which collects the data you're interested in, although that will take a lot of time and effort to get what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

i think mortal online released a map showing locations of player deaths some time back,

however why not think of it another way, give a few companies a call and tell them what you are doing and if they are willing to help, tell them anything you learn you will share with them, i'm sure some will be more than willing to pass some free work your way